# One fixed width centered div and 2 auto on sides

Tags: css

So, i have a fixed width div that should go on middle of the page, but before it& after it, i should have auto width divs that span from edge to edge of the page, like this:

```
<div class="left">Content goes from left edge of screen to center div</div>
<div class="center">Fixed width div that is always centered</div>
<div class="right">Content goes from center div to right edge of screen</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hww17nzL/2/
Any suggestions how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) on a container element.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.center {
  flex: 0 0 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Content goes from left edge of screen to center div</div>
  <div class="center">Fixed width div that is always centered</div>
  <div>Content goes from center div to right edge of screen</div>
</div>
```

Comment: very good answer. one problem is that `flex` is not supported by IE10 and lower. just something to keep in mind

Answer (score 0):

there are a number of ways to do this. you can use `display:table-cell` 
without any more specific requirements from you...i cannot say which would be best for you to use

let me know if this works for you

see snippet or > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hww17nzL/7/)

```css
.center {
    width:300px;
    text-align:center;

    
}
.left {

}
.right {

}
div {
  display:table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">Content goes from left edge of screen to center div</div>
<div class="center">Fixed width div that is always centered</div>
<div class="right">Content goes from center div to right edge of screen</div>
```

Comment: Actually, if he wants to use: display:table, OP must add container, and display:table-cell on all inner divs. Check your example on different screen resolutions....